# How to render sharepoint 2013 rest api data into a list/library view with javascript?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, javascript, library, template

I am downloading data from a sharepoint 2013 library and custom list, using the rest API (with CAML query), and I get back JSON data. Is there a javascript library out there that can take that JSON data and render it into a listview control, such that it would look exactly like, if I literally put a list/library webpart onto the page (out of the box style)?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at https://dev.office.com/fabric#/components/detailslist

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just use a List View web part?

Comment: The fabric solution is too code heavy and the results looks too new/modern from the sp2013 style. And I want to do this because in other cases I make my own JSON data and want to use this for that too.